# As a relatively new Destiny player (only level 8), how do I get to additional story missions?

Tags: destiny

I've completed all the missions on earth and the moon, how do I get to the Mars and Venus missions that I see being discussed? All I seem to have available is to do patrol missions on earth (somewhat entertaining, but doesn't seem to be leading anywhere), or sign up for Crucible matches. The latter are definitely not fun, as I seem to always be the only level 8 in a group of 40's and I end up being killed almost instantly every time I enter the battle. There doesn't seem to be anything for me to do at the Tower (or else if there is, I'm not recognizing it). There has to be something that I haven't completed, need to do, ...?

Comment: From memory you need to reach a certain level before being able to access the newer missions. By re-running the earlier campaign missions, or just roaming around Earth/the Moon, you can find "events" that randomly appear.

Comment: Level 12 unlocks Venus. Level 16 unlocks Mars. To get there you'll have to just do some patrol missions or a bit of Crucible until you level up. Also, if there are any bounties you can do, grab those. They give you CRAZY amounts of exp each day.

Comment: @DisturbedNeo OK, more patrolling it is. I don't understand bounties, but it sounds like I need to find out how to do them. Thank you

Comment: Ok, so you go to Xander 99-40 in the Tower, he's the Bounty Tracker. You'll have I think 4 bounties to choose from at your level? (Maybe 6, not sure). You pick those up and they'll have specific objectives. The Vanguard ones tend to be doing story missions on Hard, killing specific enemies, doing particular strikes or doing a number of patrol missions. Once you've completed the objective of a Bounty, you can turn it back in to Xander. The rewards will be some Vanguard Reputation and a chunk of exp.

Comment: @DisturbedNeo - I'd found Xander, signed up for a couple bounties, didn't know that I had to go back to him to collect reward. Thank you.

Comment: As a note, you no longer have to go back to the bounty NPC.  You can turn in bounties on the quest screen.